# Free space disappearing on CF card - WinCE

Tags: windows-ce, compact-flash

I have an embedded PC running Windows CE and I'm connected to it via telnet. Few days ago all free space started to disappearing. I deleted a few log files to free up some space, rebooted the device and all free space was gone. There is only a few folders (most of them are empty) and files on the card and none of them is growing in size. Is there any way how to figure out where all the free space is disappearing (maybe some hidden file)? I can only access the device via telnet or ftp. I'll provide any further details if needed.

Comment: Try using `dir` to look for hidden files via telnet. Have a good look in `%appdata%`

Comment: Just searched every folder on the CF card with `dir /a:h` command... no hidden files

Comment: Are you sure the CF card isn't failing? They have a limited lifespan when you are writing a lot of data to them.

Comment: @James I store results (aprox 7kb files) on that card every 10 minutes for about 4 months... I think it's not that much + the files are piling on the card, so the card isn't overwrited at one space too often... but I'm not sure how much the card was used before I started to using it, so it is possible

Comment: @Ashtray I can't locate %appdata% folder... I tried `cd %appdata%` and locating folder manually in `\Documents and Settings\User\ `. BTW I forgot to mention that the OS is not present on the CF card.

Comment: @0x0000eWan: Is there no way you can get physical access to the device? If possible it might be worth checking the card on a Windows PC and running chkdsk etc. assuming the file system is standard FAT 32. But I suspect that the card might be worn out in which case you would want to replace it completely.

Comment: @James Unfortunately no, the embedded PC is in different country. The best bet will probably be replacing the card then...